# Prestashop doesn't show error reporting + blank pages

Tags: prestashop

Prestashop shows blank pages. When i try to enter the admin page no css and js is showing so i can't configure anything.
I think the css and js is not being loaded properly on my site.

When I try to debug the site by editing define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
no errors are showing.

Comment: Are you enabled the display errors on your hosting?

Comment: Right click your site's home page and select view source (in your lang: paginabron weergeven ;). You get the following error: <meta property="og:title" content="<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in <b>/home/partydre/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/ad/6b/8f/ad6b8f14a3f090c7db975daddd5a96a3204e8688.file.header.tpl.php</b> on line <b>147</b><br />

Comment: @Aurora THANK YOU SO MUCH!! turns out I needed extension php_mbstring.dll enabled

Comment: Well, you're welcome. It's a great day for finding hidden little sneaky errors like this :)

Comment: You could also look into your server's Apache/Nginx logs